# How to use only parenthesis without the function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

The question may not be clear, so I will clear that here. I am using require.js to import a script in script. Here is a piece of code :

```
 var vr = {};
 vr.example = function(func) {
 return require(["https://example.com"], func);
 };
```

So, now I am able to call it by :

```
vr.example( function() { .... });
```

But, I am thinking about not writing the function everytime I have to call it. I would like to write something like this :

```
 vr.example({ ... });
```

And the result should be same. But I can't understand how to do it. So please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't be bothered to type "`function`", use `() => ...` fat arrow functions instead…? There's no way to make this *even* shorter and still use functions.

Comment: What will be in `{ ... }`? Is the callback will be the same every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you want can't be done in JavaScript ! But there is a way to do, by making an interpreter. Here is a basic example. I don't really recommend it, well I am showing you just a possibility ;)

```
window.InterpretData = function() {
    var el = document.querySelectorAll("script[type='text/test']") // You can change it anyway !
    for(var i = 0; i < el.length; ++i) { // You can use i++ instead of ++i, but ++i is much optimised for this function, watch out their differences in the internet.
      var val = el[i].innerHTML
      var crt = document.createElement("script")
      crt.id = "InterpretedScript"
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(crt) // Creating a new script element
      val = val.replace(/\.example\(\{([\S\s]*?)\}\)/gm, function(_, a) { // Wish you are familiar with regular expressions
          a = ".example( function() {" + a + "})"
          document.getElementById("InterpretedScript").innerHTML += a;
      }
   }
}
```

Now you can do :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <script type="text/test">
     // Defining 
     var vr = {};
     vr.example = function(func) {
        return require(["https://example.com"], func);
      };
     // Calling
     var.example({ ... })
  <script>
  <script>
     new InterpretData()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output :

```
 vr.example({ ... }) converts to vr.example( function() { ... })
```

Well, remember this example is just to give you an idea about a possibility to solve your problem. It's not the perfect solution though you can't again declare the "example()" to any other constant / variables, that contain different parameters ! So, the only way lies to either use ES6's fat arrows (=>) or just declare the function earlier and go on reusing it ! If you have to support old browsers than go with reusing technique shown by @mbojko, or just go with ES6's fat arrows, said earlier by @deceze. So, want do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to pass a block of code not wrapped with a function? Short answer: you can't do that in JavaScript. And require.js does expect a callback function at any rate.

If the callback function is reusable, you can declare it once and reuse it like:

```
function myReusableCallback(args) {
//...
}

vr.example(myReusableCallback);
```

And that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `require()` function returned from the `vr.example()` takes a callback function and since this callback function is usually provided by the invocation of vr.example, it, therefore, means you can't necessarily call it with and object as you want to. So you can only use an object if there is no callback expected by the `require()` an or if you have a static function that you want to be executed all the time then you can implement the function inside of the vr.example and then just pass the object which you need to use inside the function.

Answer (score -3):

It's not possible because `{}` is not a function, it's an object.

You can try it out yourself using `typeof({})` and compare it to `typeof(() => {})` or `typeof(function() {})`

Comment: "*It's not possible because {} is not a function, it's an object.*" it *might* also be a code block. However, it will never be interpreted as such in an expression context.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, in a different situation than the one harisu describes it could be something else. If I edit it to "`{}` by itself is not a function, it's an object", would you agree?